# jquery replace YouTube iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube

If a YouTube iframe embed code is ...

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/dd8W4PNUU3Q?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

how can you extract `dd8W4PNUU3Q` ie, the video id

and replace the entire iframe with

```
<img style="background-image:url('http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/dd8W4PNUU3Q/hqdefault.jpg');" class="someClass"/>
```

and wrap the image with a `<a>` giving...

```
<a href="http://www.MYURL.com/?v=dd8W4PNUU3Q"><img style="background-image:url('http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/dd8W4PNUU3Q/hqdefault.jpg');" class="someClass"/></a>
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? is this supposed to work in youtube site with some kind of script? bookmarklet? or with embedded youtube in your site?

Comment: I'd be curious to understand the end goal. If you're doing this client side, the player has already been invoked and is showing the player image. You just don't want the player to be embedded? This is a fairly data- and code-heavy way to do this; but again, I don't necessarily understand the big picture and I could be wrong.

Comment: Do you need the complete js solution  or is pseudo coding you to the solution is enough? I'm not sure I have the time to write the whole thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var RE = /embed\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})/;

jQuery( "iframe" ).each(function(){

var id = ( this.src.match( RE ) || [] )[1];

    if( id ) {
    jQuery( this ).replaceWith( '<a href="http://www.MYURL.com/?v='+id+'">'+
                                '<img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/'+id+'/hqdefault.jpg"'+
                                ' class="someClass" /></a>' );
    }

});
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4E3DH/1/