# jquery function replaces all iframes with the same thing

Tags: jquery

I have multiple iframes on my page and this jQuery replaces them all with the same thing an **example here** http://jsfiddle.net/yusaf/g6Mdq/4/ as you will see the iframe src for both are different
I have tried to implement `.each` but I have not been successfull :/

```
<script>
$(function (){
    if($(".vid-wrap iframe").length){
        var youtubeid = $(".vid-wrap iframe").attr("src").match(/[\w\-]{11,}/)[0];

        $(".vid-wrap iframe").replaceWith('<a onclick="window.open(&#39;http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=' + youtubeid +'&vq=medium&#39;,&#39;Video&#39;,&#39;width=560, height=315&#39;); return false;"><img style="width:480px;height:360px;background-image:url(http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/' + youtubeid +'/hqdefault.jpg);" class="someClass" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/--0FurTdrYzg/Tsj3RPXGz4I/AAAAAAAAAGI/mm_4UvmoD-A/s1600/standard.png"/></a>');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you think of writing your code not all on one line?

Comment: @Eric try the jsfiddle if that helps

Comment: That's equally useless. Smamatti has fixed it now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery replace YouTube iFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203956/jquery-replace-youtube-iframe/8204030)

Comment: Esailja no its not its a problem i have with the jquery i have come up with an alternative solution and it will not work as it replaces all iframes its an answer to that question but it has a problem, possible duplicate?!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/g6Mdq/18/

That should do it

Comment: but all im doing is getting the src and using it to hyperlink an image.

Comment: It's terrible practice to add onclick handlers through html strings!

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
$(function (){
    $(".vid-wrap iframe").each(function() {
        var youtubeid = $(this).attr("src").match(/[\w\-]{11,}/)[0];

        $(this).replaceWith(
            $('<a />').click(function() {
                 window.open(
                     'http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=' + youtubeid +'&vq=medium',
                     'Video',
                     'width=560, height=315'
                 );
            }).append(
                '<img style="width:480px;height:360px;background-image:url(http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/' + youtubeid +'/hqdefault.jpg);" class="someClass" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/--0FurTdrYzg/Tsj3RPXGz4I/AAAAAAAAAGI/mm_4UvmoD-A/s1600/standard.png"/>'
            )
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: @Yusaf: Is it beyond your ability to add missing parentheses?

Comment: I've not been writing jquery for long, it's difficult for me, and your recent edit hasn't worked

Comment: @Yusaf: That's because the javascript is using `.vid-wrap`, and your HTML is using `video-wrap`! [It works after that is fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/g6Mdq/17/)

Comment: thankyou for your contribution, this was a really badly worded question aswell thankyou